# Prevenir que apps carguen contenido de mi web

Tags: php

Tengo una web con algunos videos y me dado cuenta que alguna app, como wiseplay, estan cargando contenido de mi web. La web esta compuesta por una pagina de inicio ejemplo.com/index.php donde están los enlaces a otras paginas con diferentes contenidos ejemplo.com/pag1.php, ejemplo.com/pag2.php. Como puedo evitar que dichas apps carguen mi contenido?
Quizás, hacer un session_start en index.php y pasar algún cookies. Y si dicho cookies no esta en pag1 o pag2 se redirija a index.php. Estaría agradecido si alguien puede guiarme con este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se llama **hotlink**:

> El hotlink, también conocido como Hotlinking, es una práctica utilizada a menudo por ladrones de contenido para usar tus imágenes como propias, utilizando tu ancho de banda en el proceso. En este artículo, explicaremos en detalle qué es y te mostraremos cómo evitar que suceda.

Con el Htaccess

Puedes bloquear las imágenes, videos etc por dominio o mostrar una en concreado según quien la solcito.

ejemplo :

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Tienes el post completo [aqui](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/216363197-Prevenir-el-enlace-directo-de-im%C3%A1genes-hotlinking-)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no conocía esa función. Estoy usando Nginx y desafortunadamente no funciona con referer vacíos. He añadido un session_start(); con una variable y parece que consigue bloquear la carga de los videos en la app